# Can we have subdomains under stackapps.com with application or library names?

Tags: feature-request, discussion, stackapps

For example,

```
http://stackmobile.stackapps.com (George Edison)
http://stackdeck.stackapps.com (iconiK)
http://stackapplet.stackapps.com (George Edison)
```

for application or library owners?

I think even subdomain support with CNAME or redirects, it would be great to collect application sites under stackapps.com

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 6):

**Totally** agree with this. *(In fact, I would love to see the mobile site become a subdomain of StackOverflow.com!)*

There should be some sort of criterion for this, such as:

- The application should have at least *x* votes (maybe 10?)
- The application should have been in use for at least *x* days (maybe 14?)

I like the idea of redirects - that way SO doesn't have to worry about hosting, etc.